# Adapting a REGEX for SQL

Tags: sql-server, regex, t-sql

I need to write a REGEX to exclude the following codes

D57
D59
D60
D61
D62X
D63
D64
D69
D89
E85

and here is the chunk of SQL I have been using. There must be a better way by using extra brackets and the OR operator?

```
AND SUBSTRING(CODE, 1, 3) NOT LIKE 'D5[79]'
AND SUBSTRING(CODE, 1, 3) NOT LIKE 'D6[0-49]'
AND SUBSTRING(CODE, 1, 3) NOT IN ('D89','E85')
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? Postgres? The `LIKE` operator does not support regular expressions.

Comment: The answer depends on your database engine, something you failed to specify.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I cannot get to the config manager to look up the engine details but here is the spec from the About menu. Does this help?Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio      10.50.1600.1
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools      10.50.1600.1
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)      6.1.7601.17514
Microsoft MSXML      3.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer      9.0.8112.16421
Microsoft .NET Framework      2.0.50727.5472
Operating System      6.1.7601

Comment: Those are all **client** tools, not the actual DBMS you are using. But I would assume you are using Microsoft SQL Server as the DBMS

Comment: indeed seems to be Microsoft SQL Server... for LIKE you can use just a few metachars, take a look here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes Microsoft SQL Server is the Database Management System. Is this also the engine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you DBA allows SQLCLR you can add a function to perform REGEX You can check out:
[Use-RegEx-in-SQL-with-CLR-Procs.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/85954/Use-RegEx-in-SQL-with-CLR-Procs.)

You can equally use TSQL to parse and exclude the codes. To parse the codes you can use any variety of string splitters. Check out: [Split strings the right way – or the next best way](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings) In my example I created a table with codes then used the splitter function with a NOT IN to exclude the codes.

```
--create Table
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Codes](
    [ID] [int] NULL,
    [Item] [varchar](6) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

--insert values
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Codes]([ID], [Item])
SELECT 1, N'A6' UNION ALL
SELECT 2, N'D60' UNION ALL
SELECT 3, N'G56' UNION ALL
SELECT 4, N'A34' UNION ALL
SELECT 5, N'D61'

--setup test
DECLARE @inString VARCHAR(100)

SET @inString = 'D57 D59 D60 D61 D62X D63 D64 D69 D89 E85'

SELECT *
    FROM Codes
    WHERE item NOT IN (
            SELECT Item
            FROM dbo.SplitStrings_Moden(@inString, N' ')
            )
```

Comment: @Renegin OK thanks for that, I'll give it a go. However I am considering just using a NOT IN () clause and explicitly listing the codes.